# Clearing JavaScript variables in AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a UI where I have a menu that loads a div via AJAX with content based on the menu item clicked.  My problem is I have a view that has a setInterval call in a script block and when I navigate to another view the script continues to run even though the script block has been removed.  What is the best practice to truly remove a script block and stop the execution of the interval?

Comment: Did you look at [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) ?

Comment: The problem is I have a method that changes the views based on which menu item is clicked and the method has no knowledge of whether there is an interval running.